# How to estimate count for Pandas dataframe column values based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given a pandas DataFrame `df` of the following format:-

```
StudyNo   Condition1      Condition2      ResultVal
1222          25              30              0.5
1245          30              45              0.12
1672          40              15              0.46
1222          25              30              0.95
1245          30              45              0.88
1245          30              45              0.23
```

I would like to calculate `frequency/count` of the number of `ResultVal` attributes existing in the dataset for a specific `StudyNo` under a given `Condition1` and `Condition2`. There are no exactly duplicate rows in this dataset.

e.g. for `StudyNo` **1245** at `Condition1` of **30** and `Condition2` of **45**, the `count` would be **3** (because **3** `ResultVal` attributes exist for this aspect). Also, I would like to print out a list of `StudyNo`, `Condition1` and `Condition2` in cases wherein **< =1** `ResultVal` attributes exist (which in this example would be `[1672,40,15]`.

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` "StudyNo", "Condition1" and "Condition2" and transform `count` of "ResultVal" to create column "Frequency".

Then create a boolean mask for rows where "Frequency" is less than or equal to 1 and filter the rows that satisfy it.

```
cols = ['StudyNo','Condition1','Condition2']
df['Frequency'] = df.groupby(cols)['ResultVal'].transform('count')
appears_only_once = df.loc[df['Frequency'] <= 1, cols].to_numpy().tolist()
```

Output:

```
   StudyNo  Condition1  Condition2  ResultVal  Frequency
0     1222          25          30       0.50          2
1     1245          30          45       0.12          3
2     1672          40          15       0.46          1
3     1222          25          30       0.95          2
4     1245          30          45       0.88          3
5     1245          30          45       0.23          3
```

The list:

```
[[1672, 40, 15]]
```